# Basic Auth does not work from frontend in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, authorization

I use express,mongodb,passportjs for backend.

I tested my backend with postman for basic auth with email & password.It works nice.
But when I send email and password from frontend which is give below.
the output show me request  failed with status code 401.
My frontend Code is given below:`

```
loginSuccess3=(event)=>{
        var session_url = 'https://myybackend.herokuapp.com/auth/';
        const{email,password}=this.state;
        const tokenStr='masterKey';
        axios.post(session_url, 
            { auth: {
                email: email,
                password: password}
            },
            {headers: {
                'Authorization':'Basic',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            }
        }
        //,
        //{ headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization' : `Bearer  ${tokenStr}`} }
        //{ headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} }
        ).then(function(response) {
            alert('Authenticated');
        }).catch(function(error) {
            alert('Error on Authentication'+error);
        });
    }`
```

Could anybody help me?

Comment: It's always wierd with those requests packages. I would recommend setting manual header. You just need to encode your credentails like `password:user` with base64 and then set in the header `Authorization: 'Basic ${btoa("email:password")}` 
 https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_btoa.asp

Comment: are you sure you are passing the right email and password to your Axios request?do console.log(email) and console.log(password) before your axios request please share.

Comment: I also see now that you set empty basic header after you use axios to set the header. Are you sure you dont overwrite it? What happens if you remove the auth key from your headers obejct?